# Опции оптимизации компилятора gcc

Tags: gcc

Что делают опции компилятора GCC -O2 -O3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Опции, которые начинаются с O, - это указания компилятору включать различные оптимизации.

- -O0 (O ноль) - это самые простые и примитивные оптимизации.
- -O1 - более сильные оптимизации.
- -O2 - оптимизировать все, что можно, но только проверенные и надежные оптимизации.
- -O3 - жесткая и насильная оптимизация, применяются экспериментальные методы.

Каждый последующий уровень включает предыдущие. Что происходит на каждом уровне, сильно зависит от версии компилятора и нужно смотреть в документацию. (man gcc)

Обычно принято, что когда компилируют для отладки, используют максимум -O1. Для кода на боевые сервера - -O2. -O3 применяют те, кому нужны дополнительные проценты в производительности и они готовы пожертвовать тем, что приложение может быть нестабильным.

Также есть ещё -Os - оптимизировать по размеру.

Comment: Простите, не верю, что при `-O3` приложение может быть **нестабильным**.

Comment: может. Все конечно зависит от версии компилятора. Некоторые опции оптимизации, которые раньше были только на уровне O3, теперь уже и в O1.
В целом, разработчики gcc делают так, что на O2 подбирают оптимальные оптимизации. А вот в O3 может получится иногда epic fail.

Comment: @KoVadim Смотря, что вы подразумеваете под `epic fail.` Я уже написал, что, допустим, увеличение размера программы при агрессивном инлайнинге и развертке циклов может сказаться на количестве `cache miss'ов`.

Однако, я все еще не верю, что разработчики библиотек, которые ставят флаг `-O3` в своих мейкфайлах, **проверили каждую инструкцию на "стабильность".** А таких примеров предостаточно.

Comment: у меня есть печальный опыт, когда две недели искали, почему приложение раз в недельку возмет и упадет (а при 20 серверах - это почти каждые день случалось). В корках - ничего интересного. А потом выяснилось, что один с разработчиков решил перейти на O3. Как только вернули O2 - все стало вновь стабильно работать. Правда gcc был ещё версии 3.х

Comment: В моей практике *нестабильность* проявлялась, если в нужных местах не объявлять переменные как volatile. 

Код при -O3 иногда перерабатывается капитально, могут выбрасываться некоторые циклы, функции реализуются инлайн, иногда переменные не вычисляются (если компилятор может вычислить значение) и т.п. 

В общем gcc -S и см. ассемблер. Для любителей кода весьма поучительно.

Answer (score 7):

Различие опций в том, что `-O2` предоставляет некоторый набор оптимизаций, не изменяющих соотношение **скорость-размер**, а `-O3` добавляет оптимизации, которые чаще всего полагаются на подход *"занять больше места, но работать быстрее".*

> -O3
>   Optimize yet more. -O3 turns on all optimizations specified by -O2 and also turns on the -finline-functions, -funswitch-loops, -fpredictive-commoning, -fgcse-after-reload and -ftree-vectorize options.

Более подробно по некоторым опциям:

`-finline-functions` - попытка эвристически инлайнить функции, в общем случае неслабо увеличивает размер программы, что, опять же приводит к двояким результатам - с одной стороны, мы неслабо экономим на передаче параметров, с другой, помогаем **кэшу процессора больше мазать** из-за возросшего размера набора инструкций. Более подробно (старое правда, но смысл все тот же) [**здесь.**](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2001-08/msg01337.html)

Стоит также изучить опцию `-finline-limit`.

`-funswitch-loops` - ручной разворот циклов, которые копилятор посчитал пригодными для анроллинга. *Ситуация схожая с инлайнингом функций, может быть лучше, может быть хуже.*

`-fpredictive-commoning` - переиспользование результатов прошлых итераций циклов, насколько я знаю, имеет больше смысла полагаться на аппаратную реализацию `Predictive Commoning`, однако, может быть полезно.

---

Про векторизацию при `-ftree-vectorize` и `fgcse-after-reload` можете прочитать самостоятельно [**здесь.**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)