# Как отключить оптимизацию в pro-файле?

Tags: c++, gcc, qmake

В компиляторе gcc есть [параметр оптимизации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/45533/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-gcc), где выбирается уровень оптимизации. Однако для qt отключение оптимизации выглядит так:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O3
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O1
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2 
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O0 //аналогично для DEBUG
```

Вопрос: почему я должен отключать каждый уровень, если каждый последующий(по возрастанию) уровень включает в себя предыдущий? Могу ли я просто написать `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O3` чтобы отключить всю оптимизацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компилятор GCC имеет несколько уровней оптимизации от -O0 (без оптимизации) до -O3 (максимальная оптимизация). Уровни -O2 и -O3 включают оптимизации, которые делает -O1, и -O3 включает оптимизации, которые делает -O2. Но когда речь идет об отключении оптимизации, флаги -O не работают накопительно. Это означает, что использование -O3 не включает -O2, -O1 и -O0.

Поэтому, если ты хочешь убедиться, что вся оптимизация отключена, тебе нужно явно отключить каждый уровень оптимизации. Вот почему ты видишь, что каждый уровень вычитается из `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE` в файле Qt.pro

Однако, чтобы отключить все оптимизации, тебе следует просто установить уровень оптимизации на -O0, который является уровнем без оптимизации. В QMake это выглядело бы так:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -O0
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2 -O3 -O1
```

Это удалит флаги -O2, -O3 и -O1 из конфигурации релиза и добавит флаг -O0, что в итоге отключит все оптимизации.

Comment: это что чат gpt???

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: Нет, это нет чатгпт